# Limit how many people can self-signup for an Azure AD application

Tags: azure-active-directory

I would like to allow people to self-assign themselves to a AzureAD authed application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/manage-self-service-access

But since I have a limited number of licenses for said application, I want self-assigning to fail once the application has been assigned to N users. Is there a way to do this in Azure AD?

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping that one of the Entitlement Management or Governance offerings from Azure AD would enable this, but I wasn't able to find anything. One approach could be to create an access package to allow access requests to - say - a security group:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/accesspackage?view=graph-rest-1.0

Then listen for directory changes using the Microsoft Graph API for additions to that security group.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-users?tabs=http

Once the security group contains the maximum number of messages, disable the access package.

Shame that this isn't a built in feature.